# How to display timer in activity?

Tags: android, timer, android-activity

I need to display a time duration on a few of my Activities within the application. The timer starts when one of the Activity starts.

- Should I use service for the timer ?
- Is this the best way ?
- Or should I start thread from one of the Activity ?

Comment: Let me clarify the question a little:  the timer should be accessible across multiple activities. 
The other completely different approach is to store the start time, then in each activity checks the current time, minus the start time, and update the duration gui.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in the use case you're describing it would be best to *store* time stamps (see [Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)) and *calculate* the deltas for GUI use. If you need to display a real-time clock in one of your activities you can create a separate thread in that activity just to update the clock.

Answer (score 1):

Well, depending on how much interface work you need to display your progress, I would start a thread within the activity and then create a timer that checks the status of the thread progress and updates the interface as needed. Services are good for background tasks that don't require a lot of interface notification/updates.

Here's an example from a project I'm currently working on (UpdateListRunnable just calls "notifyDataSetChanged()" on my list adapter. I do it multiple times in the code so I encapsulated it in a class. Also, updateHandler is just a regular Handler instance):

```
@Override
public void run() {
    Timer updateProgressTimer = null;
    UpdateItem currentItem = null;

    for(int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
        currentItemIndex = i;
        currentItem = items.get(i);

        if (currentItem.isSelected() == true) {
            updateProgressTimer = new Timer();

            updateProgressTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    updateHandler.post(new UpdateListRunnable());
                }
            }, 0, 2000); // check every 2 seconds

            lookupDb.downloadUpdate(currentItem);

            currentItem.setUpToDate(true);
            currentItem.setStatusCode(UpdateItem.UP_TO_DATE);
            currentItem.setProgress(0);
            updateProgressTimer.cancel();

            updateHandler.post(new UpdateListRunnable());
        } // end if its the database we are hosting on our internal server
    } // end for loop through update items

    currentItemIndex = -1;
} // end updateThread run
```